# C - printf() not working but puts() is working fine

Tags: c

```
void read_class_information(head* beginning, int scale_type) {
    puts("hello");
    // printf("hello");
}
```

I have a simple function called by main and printf() and fprintf() to stdout does not seen to work within it. On the other hand, puts() works fine.  I have no files open at the time of the printf() call or any errors.  Any suggestions to what the problem might be? Thanks.

Comment: try `printf("hello\n");` or `printf("hello"); fflush(stdout);`

Comment: Add `"\n"` to the end of the `printf` string or `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf`. Because `stdout` is (generally) line buffered and will not flush until a new line is encountered. `puts` adds a trailing newline.

Comment: Puts() adds a newline. stdout is line buffered.

Comment: `puts` adds a trailing newline to stdout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `printf()` does not flush the output stream automatically. On the other hand `puts()` adds a new line `'\n'` at the end of the passed string. So it's working because the `'\n'` flushes de `stdout`.

Try

```
printf("hello\n");
```

Or, explicitly flush `stdout`

```
fflush(stdout);
```

right after the `printf()` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the new line character (`'\n'`) at the end of your statement, also make sure you have the appropriate headers.

Comment: The back tick was inserted by the OP trying to escape the code.

Answer (score 0):

By default, stream buffering is set to **line buffered**, which means nothing is really sent to the stream until a new line character `\n` is found. The three buffering methods are:

- `_IONBF`: unbuffered
- `_IOLBF`: line buffered
- `_IOFBF`: full buffered

You can change the buffering method for any stream. In this case, you may want to change the buffering method for `stdout`:

```
setvbuf(stdout, (char *)NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

In this way, you don't need to `fflush(stdout);` everytime you want to print something without a newline. This has some performance issues which may or not affect to you, so you decide which is better for you.

As usual, you have access to the documentation executing `man setvbuf` (if you have the docs installed, of course).